# how to say that I am a professional in

Tags: word-usage

I'm student in computing science, and I would like how to say ***that I'm a professional.***

For exemple, to say that is director :

> As the director of that group

---

So in the sentence:

**** I looked closely at the products and I see a manufacturing default in a cable connection inside the graphic card.

How to say that I'm a professionel, I replace **** by ?

> Professional consultant
>
> As a professional
>
> Care professional
>
> other

https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/en+tant+que+professionnel.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a bit confusing, but I'll try to help.

> I looked closely at the products and I **saw** a manufacturing default in a cable connection inside the graphic card. **As an IT professional**, I knew that this meant the card would be unusable until...

Comment: Or "as a computer professional".

Comment: @Andrew Sure, just insert whatever industry is relevant :)